# Need to add a link to a form in 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath, form, edit-form

I have an InfoPath form for a list in 2013.  I edited the form to include text for new additions to the list...HOWEVER, this change shows up in all versions of the form BUT for new additions (it shows up in edit, extend, cancel, etc the directions are there, but not on the "new" form).

Where could the "new" option be pulling the form from?  I need to edit that one.

Thank you!

Comment: Open up the list in SharePoint designer and make sure that your custom form is default for new items.

Comment: Glad to hear. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, open up the list in SharePoint designer and make sure that your custom form is default for new items.

[image]